# Scala vector to case class

Tags: json, scala, vector, playframework

I want to map this result query that showed `vector` to `case class`

dal:

```
def selectPerson = sql"select * from PERSON".as[(String,String)]
```

service:

```
def ListPerson: Future[Seq[(String,String)]] = { 
  db.run(GroupDealerDetailDal.selectPerson)
}
```

controller:

```
def listPerson = Action.async { implicit request =>
  GroupDealerDetailService.ListPerson.map(result =>
    Ok(Json.toJson(result.toString)))
}
```

case class:

```
case class Person(username: String, password: String)

object Person {
  implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]
}
```

the result is `Vector((prastyo,12345))`

how can I map that result to `case class Person`

so the result is `{"username" : "prastyo", "password" : "12345"}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want JSON output, so I suspect that the inner part should be something like this (not tested):

```
GroupDealerDetailService.ListPerson.map { people => Ok(
    Json.toJson(
        people map { case (username, password) =>
            Person(username, password)
        }
    )
)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want map DB result to Json response, you dont need extra `case class` and transformations.
You may use coast-to-coast design with Json writes combinators.

Simple writes

```
val u: OWrites[(String, String)] = (
  (__ \ "username").write[String] and 
  (__ \ "password").write[String]
).tupled
```

map your `(String, String)` to `JsObject`.

```
u.writes("prastyo" -> "12345")

res17: play.api.libs.json.JsObject = {"username":"prastyo","password":"12345"}
```

With `Writes.traversableWrites`

```
val s = Writes.seq(u)
```

you can map your `Vector` to `JsArray`

```
s.writes(Seq("prastyo" -> "12345"))
res16: play.api.libs.json.JsValue = [{"username":"prastyo","password":"12345"}]
```

complete controller:

```
def listPerson = Action.async {
  GroupDealerDetailService.ListPerson.map(s.writes).map(Ok(_))
}
```